# «C'est-à-dire ?» peut-il signifier «Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?»

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Est-ce qu'on peut utiliser l'expression «C'est-à-dire ?» dans le sens de «Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?»

Par exemple:

> J'ai passé une nuit blanche.
>
> ― C'est-à-dire ?
>
> ― Je n'ai pas dormi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, on peut l'entendre ainsi. (Et de *bons auteurs* utilisent *c'est-à-dire* en ce sens.)

Je ne l'utilise personnellement pas dans ce sens **à l'oral** car, contrairement à *qu'est ce que ça veut dire*, la nature interrogative de la phrase n'est pas explicite.

Quant un locuteur utilise *c'est-à-dire* il signifie en général qu'il va poursuivre son énoncé par une précision sur / une reformulation de ce qui précède :

- J'ai passé une nuit blanche.
- C'est à dire que tu n'as pas dormi.

En d'autres termes, si mon interlocuteur ne marque pas par l'intonation une finale interrogative, après un :

- C'est à dire

J'attendrai qu'il poursuive lui-même plutôt que de lui répondre immédiatement.

Une solution évidente serait d'utiliser plutôt *qu'est-ce à dire* qui marque l'interrogation mais cette inversion a vieilli, surtout à l'oral.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu veux dire par "de bons auteurs" ?

Comment: @lmc : Ha!... Bonne question! ; Cela rassemble des auteurs qui ont acquis la réputation de manier la langue correctement et aussi ceux qui ont à plusieurs reprises eu les faveurs du public / des jurys de prix littéraires. Mais bon... cela reste effectivement très subjectif. Tellement que... avec Érasme... j'utilise souvent cette désignation de façon plutôt...ironique.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, both can be used to mean the very same thing.

A difference is that *qu'est-ce à dire*, like other interrogatives using an inversion, is less mainstream and more formal. On the opposite, you might hear *qu'est-ce ça veut dire ?* (dropping *que*), *ça veut dire quoi / tu veux dire quoi ?* in colloquial spoken French.

There might also be a slight nuance. ***Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?*** often simply means that the wording of what has been said is not understood while ***qu'est-ce à dire ?*** might mean that while the words are understood, the underlying meaning need to be clarified like with *qu'est-ce que tu veux dire par là / **qu'est-ce qui est sous entendu par là** ?*

Comment: Comme pour toutes les formes interrogatives, utilisées à l'écrit par quelque... *bon auteur*... ces différentes façons de s'exprimer servent souvent à sous-entendre "*l'origine sociale*" du locuteur.

Comment: Comment prononce-t-on "qu'est-ce à dire" ?

Comment: Le plus souvent /kɛsadiʁ/, comme pourrait l'être *caisse à dire*.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 0):

The two are different words, they cannot be used in the same context to mean the same thing. "[That is](https://bitsquestions.com/family-questions-to-ask-your-parents-siblings/)" can be used to mean for example/instance. While 'What does this mean?' is used for asking a question.

Comment: The fact that the two represent two different wordings is obviously very true. However, this is **in no way** a sufficient reason for their meanings to **necessarily** differ. In this precise case, they do actually not necessarily differ.